# Fundamental group of a triangle with the three vertices identified?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Which is the fundamental group of a triangle with the three vertices identified?

I call $X$ the previous space. I take $U$ be a disk inside the triangle and $V$ the complement of a disk inside the triangle (I take them so that $U \cap V$ is homotopy equivalent to a circle). Hence $\pi_1(U \cap V)=\mathbb{Z}$, $\pi_1(U)=(0)$ and $\pi_1(V)=F^3$ is the free group on $3$ generators (i.e. it is generated by the three edges). Then, by Van Kampen

$$
\pi_1(X)=F^3/N
$$

but I cannot express the normal subgroup $N$. My intuition says that I have to obtain $\pi_1(X)=<a,b,c: abc=1>$, i.e. the free group on two generators. Is my intuition right? Can you help me please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of van Kampen's theorem that you're using, but in case you're using the combinatorial version, then it exactly says that $\pi_1(X)=\langle x,y,z\mid i(w)=1\rangle$, where $i:\pi_1(U\cap V)\to\pi_1(X)$ is induced by the inclusion and $w\in\pi_1(U\cap V)\cong\mathbb Z$ is the generator. Here $w=[\gamma]$, where $\gamma$ is the loop around the circle in the intersection. Note that this loop is homotopic to following the three edges after each other, so that $i(w)=xyz$, which is exactly the group you mentioned.

As a side note, I envision the space $V$ as follows:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the diagram

Answer (score 4):

There is a general result involving a basic construction on groupoids: given a groupoid $G$ with object set $S$ and a function $f: S \to T$ to a set $T$ one can construct a new groupoid say $f_*(G)$ with object set $T$ and with a universal property which is nicely expressed by saying that there is the  following pushout diagram of groupoids, in which $D(S)$ is the discrete groupoid on $S$:

$$ \begin{matrix}
D(S) & \xrightarrow{D(f)} & D(T) \\
\downarrow && \downarrow\\
G & \xrightarrow{\bar{f}} & f_*(G)
\end{matrix} 
$$

This idea is due to Philip HIggins, see his downloadable book [Categories and Groupoids](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html).

A particular case is when $T$ is a singleton, when we get the *universal group*  $U(G)$ of the groupoid $G$. If all the vertex groups of $G$ are trivial, then $U(G)$ is a free group.

Special cases of this construction $U(G)$ are free products of groups, and free groups.

This result has topological applications which are given in Section 9.1 of the downloadable book [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html), as they were in the 1968, 1988  differently titled editions. One has to introduce the notion of the fundamental groupoid $\pi_1(X,S)$ on a set $S$ of base points to deal adequately with the situation when one is identifying  some or all of a discrete  discrete set $S$  of points. (Of course, one can get round the problem but the idea is to "match the algebra to the geometry, not force the geometry into a particular mode simply because that mode is more familiar", as remarked, I was told, by Philip Hall.)

I published  this idea of $\pi_1(X,S)$ in 1967 in order to have a version of the van Kampen Theorem which would compute the fundamental group of the circle, which is, after all, **the** basic example in algebraic topology. I am unsure why this this idea is, almost 50 years later,  found  "ideosyncratic".

Compare with this [mathoverflow question and answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what statement of Van Kampen you are using, but loosely speaking, $N$ is generated by loops of the form $i(\omega)j(\omega)^{-1}$ where $i$ and $j$ are induced by the inclusions $U\cap V\to V$ and $U\cap V\to U$ respectively and $\omega\in\pi_1(U\cap V)$. For a canonical generator $\omega_0\in\pi_1(U\cap V)$ (i.e. a loop that looks like a circle in $U\cap V$), we have that $i(\omega)j(\omega)^{-1}=i(\omega)=abc$ (where $a,b,c$ denote the generators for your $F^3$, which indeed correspond to the edges of the triangle; note that we can "stretch out" $\omega_0$ in $V$ to "lie on the edges"). Therefore we indeed get $\pi_1(X)=\langle a,b,c\mid abc=1\rangle$.